# how to get the number of lines of edittext in landscape mode

Tags: android, landscape, lines

I am having issue in getting number of lines currently set in an edittext in landscape mode.
If I write 7 lines in an edittext in potrait, I can fetch the number of lines by edittext.getCountLine().

But when I am changing to landscape, the method is still giving 7 line count even though only 4 lines are there in landscape!!

Is there any way I can get current number of lines in landscape? I am calling this method of lines in onConfigurationChanged(...) method.

Thanks.

Comment: also if i set some text from preferences into edittext during activity open and try to get count line, it gives me zero initially.

Answer (score 4):

There is no any extra code you need to provide for sceern orrientation.
Try the Following code :

```
editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);  

button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
@Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
String str = editText.getText().toString();
Log.e("Entered text is : =>",str);
Log.e("total line num is : =>", ""+editText.getLineCount());`   }
    });
    `
```